# 90s bande dessinée about a steampunk/dieselpunk vehicles race, featuring a vampire car

Tags: story-identification, bandes-dessinees

I'm trying to identify a French-language *bande dessinée* that I read in the 90s (maybe early 2000s).
It was printed in the classic A4 paper format, with a cardboard hardcover.

The story was set in an early steampunk/dieselpunk 20th century and was about vehicles competing in a race, of which I can remember two of them :

1. A vampire car that drank the blood of its drivers (IIRC named "La Veuve noire" = "black widow"). I believe it would eventually win the race. It looked like a sleek black car with tinted windows, not unlike [image: picture of a black car with a long front hood]
2. A huge crewed coal-powered behemoth that would eventually explode after being overcharged by its captain.

Other lesser and unsuccessful vehicles existed but I can't recall any of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Pur-Sang : Une Aventure de Cliff Barton* (1993) by Rodolphe and Durand maybe.

From [BD Oubliées](https://bdoubliees.com/questionsarchives2300.html) ("Forgotten comics"), translated:

> The only memory I have of this comic book I'm looking for is that **there was a car race in it that was a bit fantastic because one of the competitors' cars had the particularity of running on the driver's blood** (which made for a bit of a demonic car, with lots of tubes/syringes in the cockpit). At one point, this led to the death of the driver, who was replaced by another driver. I read that about twenty years ago [...].

The cover features a human being drained of blood, and the back cover has a huge caboose-like vehicle:

[image: front cover, a 19th-century-ish steampunk vehicle crossing a checkered flag, while a man is being drained of blood by a tube in his neck]

[image: back cover, several race vehicles followed by a huge train of sorts]

---

Found with the Google query `bande dessinée "course automobile" science fiction voiture vampire` (`comics "car race" science fiction vampire car`).

Comment: That's the one! Thanks @Jenayah! You've been luckier with your search engine than me! :)